# fabricjs - Groups are not receiving mouse events

Tags: javascript, d3.js, fabricjs

I'm working on a library to wrap `FabricJS` within `d3.js`, allowing me to use d3 to create different visuals while using Canvas for the actual drawing. Nearly everything is done, but I can't get events working on group elements.

Currently I'm testing with a recreation of [d3.js's Zoomable Treemap](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/treemap.html). Everything works, but when I try to click on a node which is a `fabric.Group` object, nothing happens.

Debugging through Fabric, I found that it ends up at `_searchPossibleTargets`, which never returns any target. Doing a couple more debugging sessions and I found that the bounds of the `Group` aren't getting set. If you look at the source for the example, you'll find that all the data is set *after* it is added to the `Group`.

There is no function to recalculate the size of the group, meaning my click events are not working on the groups. While incorrect results were expected due to the values not being set `addWithUpdate` screws up the entire drawing leaving me with a jumbled up mess of a visual.

I've even tried using some of the internal functions such as `_calcBounds` after saving left/top, but it ends up with the same jumbled mess that `addWithUpdate` results in.

Worst case, I may try `KineticJS` to see if that resolves the issue since the only change I need to do is to add a Layer and change names, though if it doesn't work, then I'll be switching back to Fabric. Regardless, I'd prefer to stick with `Fabric`. Is there anyway to do this?

If any more information is needed, feel free to ask.

**EDIT 1:**
Ok, I did a small example with Fabric that demos the issue: [FabricJS example](http://jsfiddle.net/2MBD8/28/)

If you click on the boxes, they should change. But if you notice, the last box doesn't work.

FabricJS working groups:

```
var r2 = new fabric.Rect({'fill':'green',
                              'width':100,
                              'height':100});
r2.selectable = false;
var g1 = new fabric.Group([r2], {'top':0,
                                     'left':100});
g1.selectable = false;
g1.on('mousedown', function() {
    if (r2.getFill() === 'green') {
        r2.set({'fill':'yellow'});
    } else {
        r2.set({'fill':'green'});
    }
});
can.add(g1);
```

FabricJS non-working groups, but needed for d3 usage:

```
var r3; //-just here for the group event handler
var g2 = new fabric.Group();
g2.selectable = false;

// * Add the group to canvas, then set attributes
can.add(g2);
g2.set({'top':0,
        'left':200});
g2.on('mousedown', function() {
    if (r3.getFill() === 'orange') {
        r3.set({'fill':'purple'});
    } else {
        r3.set({'fill':'orange'});
    }
});

// * Create and add the rect to the group, then set attributes
r3 = new fabric.Rect();
r3.selectable = false;

//Note: I'm using "add". If you change this to "addWithUpdate" you will see the layout/drawing issue I mentioned
g2.add(r3);
r3.set({'fill':'orange',
        'width':100,
        'height':100});
```

With my wrapper, this is how I would build that example in d3 (which would produce the same code as the second, non-working, example):

```
var g = canvasElement.append('group')
                     .attr({'top':0,
                            'left':200})
                     .on('mousedown', function() {
                         var rect = this.select('rect');
                         if (rect.attr('fill') === 'orange') {
                             rect.attr('fill', 'purple');
                         } else {
                             rect.attr('fill', 'orange');
                         }
                     });

g.append('rect')
 .attr({'fill':'orange',
        'width':100,
        'height':100});
```

Note that `selectable` is set to false by default in my wrapper.

Comment: I don't know the details of the Fabric.js implementation, but in SVG a `<g>` element doesn't have any height, width or position of its own, that could be part of the problem.

Comment: Correct, though I'm not using SVG. This wrapper I'm working on lets me use d3 with Canvas as opposed to SVG.

Comment: Just suggesting that if they are trying to mimic SVG function behaviour, that could be a problem.  Either way, I'd recommend putting  together a simplified working example so other people can see what is happening and try to debug directly.

Comment: Agreed though I'll have to see, since the wrapper hasn't been released yet. Shouldn't be too difficult though.

Comment: I saw your fiddle, it looks like a bug of fabricJS library. Please if you want open an issue to fabricjs github page. With current version of library issue still exist.